# ASP.NET MVC 5 Grid View with Search and Pagination.

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new on ASP.NET MVC 5 I have developed an Application which retrieves data from SQL database and displays it in the form of table. My challenge is that I want to implement a search functionality with pagination so that I can control a records displayed on the page, is the any tool or solution that one would recommend to someone who's new to ASP.NET MVC 5.

Technologies used in this Application:
Twitter Bootstrap
jQuery
Entity Framework

Thank you in advance.

Comment: see this https://datatables.net/

Comment: Thank you Bharat will look at it.

Comment: FooTable is good. http://fooplugins.github.io/FooTable/ Search and pagination is all client-side - feed it your whole dataset and it will handle it for you automatically, up to 100,000 rows (it claims). Quite configurable as well. It's not specific to .NET or MVC, you can use it with any server-side framework, or on its own. This is really off-topic though, SO is not a forum for recommending specific products - you can google it yourself and do some research.